# Rails (3) example drag and drop + inline editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drag-and-drop, inline-editing

Does anyone has or known a good proof of concept for a drag and drop + inline editing of a recordset?

I want to be able to load a recordset and edit it inline on the page itself + be able to drag and drop the contents of it.

What would be the best approch for such functionality?
I already found inline recordset edit for rails but that only grabs a recordset and inline makes it editable.

Any recommendations would be higly welcome thx

Answer (score 1):

You will need a combination of tutorials

- **[REMOVED]** drag and drop :
  http://webtempest.com/sortable-list-in-ruby-on-rails-3-almost-unobtrusive-jquery/
- inline : (best_in_place)
  http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing
- The first and (mainly) second part
  of this tutorial could also help solidify your knowledge
  http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Cheers

Comment: First one has been removed. Sucks because it's the only one I wanted to read. :(

Comment: For drag and drop, I just finished using the following two sites as examples: http://www.jpgenovese.com/2012/10/06/ruby-on-rails-and-jquery-ui-draggable/#comment-85 and http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/